# How to protect conditional formatting in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-conditionalformatting

I have 2 CFs in a sheet that I would like to keep upon copy/pastes you can see the range and formulas below.

```
CF1 Range : B3:H1001
CF1 Formula : =($A3<>"")*(B3="") //This one higlights the empty cells in a given range

CF2 Range : A3:R1001  // This one highlights the row if the cell in R column is No.
CF2 Formula : =$R:$R="No"
```

Is there a way to protect these CFs or apply them again after copy paste ? Thanks !

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `protect these CFs` and `apply them again after copy paste`?

Comment: When I copy paste from another range I am losing the Conditional formats that i have created. So I want them to stay like I formatted or I would like them to be applied again after the copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Can you share the sheet to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I copy paste from another range I am losing the Conditional formats that i have created. So I want them to stay like I formatted or I would like them to be applied again after the copy/paste.

From above replying, I could understand that you want to keep the conditional formats, which are `=($A3<>"")*(B3="")` for `B3:H1001` and `=$R:$R="No"` for `A3:R1001`, even when the range is copied and pasted to `B3:H1001` and `A3:R1001`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, there are no methods for directly protecting the conditional formats in Google Apps Script. So in this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose to overwrite the conditional formats when the change of conditional formats and cells using OnChange event trigger.

### Flow:

1. The range is copied and the parameters of conditional formats are changed.
2. The script is automatically run by the OnChange event trigger.
3. The existing conditional formats are deleted and new conditional formats are set.

### Usage:

#### 1. Copy and paste sample script

Please copy and paste the following sample script.

Sample script:

Please set the sheet name.

```
function onChange(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() != sheetName || e.changeType != "OTHER") return;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rules = sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  const rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([sheet.getRange("B3:H")])
    .setBackground("green")
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=($A3<>"")*(B3="")').build();
  const rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([sheet.getRange("A3:R")])
    .setBackground("green")
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$R:$R="No"').build();
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([rule1, rule2]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // This line might not be required.
}
```

- In this sample script, 2 conditional formats in your question are set as the background color of green.

#### 2. Install OnChange event trigger

[Please install the OnChange event trigger to the function of `onChange`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

#### 3. Test run

As a test run, please copy and paste the range in `sheetName`. By this, the script is run by the OnChange event trigger.

### Note:

- I think that OnEdit event trigger can be also used. But in this case, when the parameters of the conditional formats are changed, the event trigger is not run. So I used the OnChange event trigger.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [setConditionalFormatRules(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setconditionalformatrulesrules)

Comment: Hey man thank you for oyur great answer its working. But is there a faster code to do this ? I have a spreadsheet that will be working by 10 people if this script will be run at the similar time with everyone it would create some problems I think ?

Comment: @Triath Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I think that when Sheets API is used, the cost can be reduced than that of Google Spreadsheet service like `SpreadsheetApp`. And also, when you want to use it for several users, it might be required to use the lock service. But I'm not sure whether this is the suitable for your additional question. If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: No problem at all I got your point. Also it gives this error TypeError: Cannot read property "changeType" from undefined.  when I try to run the code with your if statement.

Comment: @Triath Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this sample script, OnChange event trigger is used. When the function is directly run at the script editor, such error occurs. So please be careful this. If you want to directly run the script, please remove the line of the if statement.